# How can I develop mobile applications using HTML5?

Tags: javascript, android, css, html, mobile

I am able to develop android native applications using android SDK, but now I'd like to learn how to develop mobile applications using HTML5.
Which tool is used to develop these mobile application in HTML5?
Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) is a good Javascript framework to create mobile applications. It supports all phones the utilize the webkit for their browser.

It can be wrapped in phonegap to utilize the phone specific API's. Sencha is now creating their own wrapping system to submit apps to the appstores.

Comment: There are many framework for mobile web app using HTML5 so which one is best to use ?

Comment: I have only worked with Sencha Touch but its very mature framework. It also has a very active community to provide help. Its also backed by sencha company so there is active development for it. Jquery mobile came later to the scene.

Comment: Okey,Thanks. Now i have one question : Can i develop any app using sencha touch framework that i could develop using native SDK ? And How many mobile platform sencha touch supports ?

Answer (score 4):

While your question can easily be answered by a simple search of "android html5 framework", there is [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/).

[This](http://www.web-delicious.com/7-best-mobile-web-html5-framework-for-mobile-app-development/) link was the first to show up.

Comment: [There](http://www.web-delicious.com/7-best-mobile-web-html5-framework-for-mobile-app-development/) is no framework like PhoneGap .

Comment: There are many framework for mobile web app using HTML5 so which one is best to use ?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to embed your html inside an android application, you can use the **webview** widget for android.

Now, talking about how to do your webview itselft. I would recommend to use a mobile framework to build a good looking  and accessible application without too much difficulty. I have worked with [Jquery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/), and I would say it is a good way to start.

Comment: There are many framework for mobile web app using HTML5 so which one is best to use ?

Comment: @RameshSolanki You can't really say that one is the best overall I think; you should find one that you like. I just told you that I like particularly Jquery Mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Use Apache Cordova http://cordova.apache.org/ as the container for displaying HTML 5 pages.
Use Twitter Bootstrap for creating responsive web pages which automatically resize components based on the size/type of the screen on which the app is being viewed.

Answer (score 0):

Another tool you may want to try is Tiggr (http://gotiggr.com). Tiggr is a cloud service for building HTML5 mobile apps. It comes with visual jQuery Mobile designer.

*Note: I'm the Developer Advocate for Tiggr*

Answer (score 0):

Since you're an Android developer, you're probably used to writing in Java. You might thus also want to look into Google Web Toolkit, which enables you to write HTML5 apps in Java. There are a number of different GWT libraries for mobile widgets. The questions boils down to whether you want to write in Java or in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try MoSync (www.mosync.com) for it, the advantage of MoSync is - it's truly cross platform and it let's you write hybrid applications as well (using C++ and HTML5) and being cross platform if you write a plugin it goes on to every platform, which would mean we don't have to write separate plugins in Java, Object C, Dot Net etc. as it is the case on PhoneGap.

I wrote a [tutorial to make a HTML5 twitter client app in a minute or so using MoSync and Sencha Touch](http://ciitronian.com/blog/programming/javascript/tutorial-ios-twitter-app-in-60-seconds-using-mosync-and-sencha-touch/)  and it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [RIB](https://01.org/rib) to build your HTML5 UI and then add code to it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

[JqueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)

A unified, HTML5-based user interface system for all popular mobile device platforms, built on the rock-solid jQuery and jQuery UI foundation.

With ***Drag and Drop*** UI tool